# How to send json logs through fluentd to stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, containers, fluentd, stackdriver

I have docker containers writing logs in json format. When they run on GKE, the logs are shown in StackDriver fine, but when I run the same containers on some VM with kubernetes (not GKE) and use fluentd to route the logs to StackDriver, the log messages arrive escaped and under "log" key.

Example: {"stream":"stdout","log":"{\"time\":\"2019-07-25T09:55:18.2393210Z\", ....

How can I configure fluentd to get the logs in the same format as on GKE (without "log": and unescaped)?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider:

1. You can configure fluentd's log format with [this](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles/common-log-formats) guide.
2. You can try some reverse engineering. Fluentd config used by GKE can by studied at following path on fluend Pod: `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/containers.input.conf`
3. You can directly check the GKE config in a `ConfigMap` called `fluentd-gcp-config-v1.2.5`. There is some useful information regarding how to config fluentd as non-managed. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: I tried to take configuration through kubectl and from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp/fluentd-gcp-configmap.yaml.
In the both cases the result did not change: still 'log' property appears in stackdriver

Comment: There are two types of fluentd-gcp configs, old one and new one. The latter seems to alter the 'log' field. Which one are you using?($LOGGING_STACKDRIVER_RESOURCE_TYPES var controls this)

Comment: Rename the field 'log' to a more generic field 'message'. This way the
fluent-plugin-google-cloud knows to flatten the field as textPayload
instead of jsonPayload after extracting 'time', 'severity' and
'stream' from the record.

Comment: We need jsonpayload, so textpayload won't help